# Soundtouch for iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio

Has someone been able to make
http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/
work for iPhone?

Simple Xcode Demo would be helpful.

I'd just like to play a soundeffect with some pitch manipulation.

thx
chris

Comment: I'm not sure how to integrate SoundTouch to compile on iOS, but the guy in this question got it to work:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3963827/207682

Answer (score 2):

The best way to implement audio effects using *SoundTouch* is using also *SoundStretch*.

You can download the source code of both from here http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/sourcecode.html

> SoundStretch is a command-line program that performs SoundTouch
> library effects on WAV audio files. The program is a source code
> example how SoundTouch library routines can be used to process sound
> in other programs, but it can be used as a stand-alone audio
> processing tool as well.
>
> SoundStretch features:
>
> - Reads & writes `.wav` audio files
> - Allows very broad parameter adjustment ranges:
> - **Tempo & Playback Rate** adjustable in range -95% .. +5000%
> - **The sound Pitch (key)** adjustable in range -60 .. +60 semitones (+- 5 octaves).
> - **Beats-Per-Second (BPM)** detection that can adjust tempo to match with the desired BPM rate.
> - Full source codes available
> - Command-line interface allows using the *SoundStretch* utility for processing `.wav` audio files in batch mode
> - Supports processing `.wav` audio streams through standard input/output pipes
> - *SoundStretch* uses the *SoundTouch* library routines for the audio procesing.

**Example of use:**

```
NSArray *effects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-rate=-22", nil];
NSURL *audio = [self base:input output:output effects:effects];
```

Where `base:output:effects` is defined as:

```
- (NSURL *)base:(NSURL *)input output:(NSURL *)output effects:(NSArray *)effects{
    int _argc = 3 + (int)[effects count];
    
    const char *_argv[]={"createWavWithEffect",[[input path] UTF8String], [[output path] UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String],[@"" UTF8String]};
    
    for (int i=0; i<[effects count]; i++) {
        _argv[i+3] = [effects[i] UTF8String];
    }
    createWavWithEffect(_argc, _argv);

    // IMPORTANT! Check the file size, maybe you will need to set by yourself

    return output;
}
```

If you don't want to compile by yourself SoundTouch, I have shared a GitHub repository with that libraries compiled for `armv7`, `armv7s`, `arm64`, `i386` and `x86_64`

https://github.com/enrimr/soundtouch-ios-library

And if you want to use SoundTouch by yourself without using SoundStretch, you have to add SoundTouch directory (which includes libSoundTouch.a and the directory with headers) in your Xcode project.

**For SWIFT projects:**

Programming with SWIFT you can't import a .h so you will need to create a .h file named `<Your-Project-Name>-Bridging-Header-File.h`
Then reference it in your projects build settings (under "Swift Compiler" look for "Objective C Bridging Header") with:

```
$(SRCROOT)/<Your-Project-Name>-Bridging-Header.h
```

And now you must be able to use SoundTouch class.

**For Objective-C projects:**

Include the following line

```
#include "SoundTouch.h"
```

in your controller file.

Implementation of `createWavWithEffect`:

```
int createWavWithEffect(const int nParams, const char * const paramStr[])
{
    WavInFile *inFile;
    WavOutFile *outFile;
    RunParameters *params;
    SoundTouch soundTouch;

    fprintf(stderr, _helloText, SoundTouch::getVersionString());

    try 
    {
        // Parse command line parameters
        params = new RunParameters(nParams, paramStr);

        // Open input & output files
        openFiles(&inFile, &outFile, params);

        if (params->detectBPM == TRUE)
        {
            // detect sound BPM (and adjust processing parameters
            //  accordingly if necessary)
            detectBPM(inFile, params);
        }

        // Setup the 'SoundTouch' object for processing the sound
        setup(&soundTouch, inFile, params);

        // clock_t cs = clock();    // for benchmarking processing duration
        // Process the sound
        process(&soundTouch, inFile, outFile);
        // clock_t ce = clock();    // for benchmarking processing duration
        // printf("duration: %lf\n", (double)(ce-cs)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        // Close WAV file handles & dispose of the objects
        delete inFile;
        delete outFile;
        delete params;

        fprintf(stderr, "Done!\n");
    } 
    catch (const runtime_error &e) 
    {
        // An exception occurred during processing, display an error message
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to use "createWavWithEffect" thank you. I'm using SoundTouch 1.8

Comment: Could you please add the implementation of 'createWavWithEffect'?

Comment: @EnriMR: Not able to compile with swift. I've added bridging header and `#import "SoundTouch.h"` into that header but getting errors in the .h files downloaded from `https://github.com/enrimr/soundtouch-ios-library`

Comment: @Yogi : Are you able to compile with swift and adding this files using bridging header?

Comment: @Yogi here you are ;)

Comment: @KetanParmar I think some new version of Swift could require a different bridge implementation, unfortunately, I haven't use it since some years ago. If you have the solution, please, share it here.

Comment: @KetanParmar You will need to write an Objective-C wrapper class. for that.

Comment: @EnriMR Thanks, I am going to try it now!

Comment: @EnriMR : Okay. Thanks

Comment: @Yogi : How? can you please share some sample code or hint?

Comment: @KetanParmar We can not use C++ code directly in Swift. First we will have to write a .mm file with .h header. I this file we will call C++ functions and those should be wrapped in Objective-C functions. Now these Objective-C functions can be called in Swift class. Hope this clears some doubts.

Comment: @Yogi: I understand that. But is there any tool or command line command for this conversion? Because EnriMR's git repository has only .h files and one .a file. So, how to create the equivalent .mm files?

Comment: @Yogi: Can you share that wrapper files if you have created? I'll be very thankful if you can do.

Comment: @KetanParmar: My code is not in a working condition yet. Trying to get hold of this.

Comment: @EnriMR: The functions openFiles, setup etc. are all in main.cpp from Soundtouch library. How can I make those available in Objective-C? Could you please explain?

Comment: @Yogi: Okay. No worries. Thanks for your support. If you got working code please post it somewhere.

Comment: @KetanParmar I will surely be happy to help, currently I am trying to figure out error ':createWavWithEffect(int, char const* const*)", referenced from:
      -[SoundTouchWrapper base:output:effects:] in SoundTouchWrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
' 
Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219998/discussion-between-yogi-and-ketan-parmar).